# Bootstrap 4 Nav menu showing incorrectly

Tags: bootstrap-4

working with php and WAMP3 localhost and i just wanted to add a bootstrap nav menu, first off i tried using CDN and it was showing the menu correctly. Then i tried downloading bootstrap 4 and then putting the source file on my file system locally and this is the result!

[image]

As you can see in my code inspector all the necessary file are loaded correctly. And all i did was copied the bootstrap NAV from bootstrap example as shown below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample09">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown09" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown09">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: may be you copied code from wrong doc. try this [doc](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

Comment: Hope is isnt working, anyway i am starting from scratch and going through one step at the time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6, you need jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js and tether.min.js version 1.4.0. your jquery version might be higher than what bootstrap alpha supports

Comment: No that can't be the reason why because i have it working without using php header and footer include

Comment: Can you show your script and css import in html? One of the reason could be apache server has no access to your css and js folder

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar code is for Bootstrap 4 beta (2).

You should:

- Upgrade *or*
- Check the [old docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) for the right syntax

Example (for BS4 alpha):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```